# Does sectionNameKeyPath allow a NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Does it?

I have for my NSFetchedResultsController,

```
sectionNameKeyPath:@"month.month_"
```

month refers to parent relationship. And month_ is a NSNumber in my Core Data model.

Should this work? Or must month_ be a string? And if so, is there any other way around?

Documentation is not very clear on this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Nuno

Comment: I did! Just got it working! Turns out my problem was that I was not implementing - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section. In the absence of this I wasn't getting any sections! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does allow for a NSNumber.

The reason for it not to be working in my case, was that I was not implementing

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

In the absence of this, it wasn't displaying the table view with sections. Leading me to believe that maybe it didn't support for a NSNumber. But it does.